# Java Splitting Regex Issues inside quotations

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split this string

```
String string1 = "Employee:\"Timothy Jones\" and Job:\"Senior Management\" and Hired:\"2003\"";
```

using

```
String[] splitArray = string1.split("###");
```

But I am having a lot of trouble with the regex to split it into what I want. My desired result is

```
employee, Timothy Jones, and, Job, Senior Mangement, and Hired, 2010
```

The main problem seems to be the text inside the quotes splitting on the whitespace.

Comment: `Employee:”Timothy Jones” and Job:”Senior Management” and Hired:”2003”` is not a valid string in Java. Please format your code and fix it so that it compiles before you post it.

Comment: this shouldn't even compile... you need to escape the double quotes then wrap the whole string in double quotes.

Comment: What kind of double-quotes is it: `”` or `"` ?

Comment: tried str.split("and|[:|\"]");
but i get 
[Employee, ”Timothy Jones” ,  Job, ”Senior Management” ,  Hired, ”2010”]

Comment: How come `and, Job,` are separate but `and Hired` is one result? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use matching instead of splitting:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+|\w+)
```

`A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+` captures all the phrases like `Timothy Jones`, `Senior Management` etc., and `\w+` captures the rest of the words.

Note, however, that this regex gives `and` and `Hired` as separate matches; I'm not sure why you would want them to be in a single match.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oP1pO5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Or with matching:

```
".*?"|\S+
```

".*?" : All phrase surrounded by double quote
 \S+ : rest of words